# PHP template system with while loop

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a simple template system because I don't want to use Smarty or anything like that.

My current problem is that I can't make 1 tag print every result from a while loop. It only prints the first result.

```
public $TplKey = array();

public function GetContent($file, $data) {
    $template = file_get_contents($file);

    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        $template = str_replace('{'.$key.'}', $value, $template);
    }

    return $template;
}

public function View($file) {
    return $this->GetContent($file, $this->TplKey);
}

public function TplKeyAdd($key, $value) {
    return $this->TplKey += array($key => $value);
}

public function testing() {
    global $DBHandle;

    $q = $DBHandle->mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM site_users");
    while($qf = $q->fetch_array()) {
        $r = $this->TplKeyAdd("var", $qf["user_name"]);
    }

    return $r;
}
```

Then, later on in my .TPL file I call `{var}`. But it only shows the first database row (as stated). I want it to show every row it can find. How can I solve this?

Comment: If you `return` in a while loop, you'll only ever get one iteration of it

Comment: @iainn Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I know you said you don't want to use an existing template system, but I'm curious why not. Aren't you just re-inventing the wheel now? You could have long since installed Smarty or Twig, learned the syntax, and then moved onto your next task by now.

Comment: @BenHillier I just want to get some experience with it. I know it's like re-inventing the weel, but I don't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue lies with how you're storing the `key` => `value` pairs in the `TplKeyAdd` method.

I believe you're after:

```
public function TplKeyAdd($key, $value) {
    return $this->TplKey[] = array($key => $value);
}
```

Also with this:

```
$this->TplKeyAdd("var", $qf["user_name"]);
```

The key you're adding every time is called "var" so each value from the database doesn't have it's own key.

**Edit:** Also as [ianinn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4680018/iainn) pointed out, you shouldn't be returning within your while look as it'll only get the first iteration.

Comment: I get "Array to string conversion" with that method. Also, since the array is already made before that function, I have to use "+=" and not "=", but that gives me "Unsupported operand types"...

Comment: I don't wish to use multiple "var" keys for every result. I wish to have one "var" key and make it print out every result if it's from a loop.

Comment: So why are you using a `while` loop when you only want one result?

Comment: You got me wrong there. I want all rows from the database table, but I want to show them all only with one "var" tag.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You want **all** your database rows to populate a single `{var}` tag?

Comment: So store the values in an array within the while loop, then concatenate using impode and then pass through TplKeyAdd